# How can i create an array based on constructor method in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods, constructor

So I've been working on my final project for c#
And i need to create 3 classes with arrays one for cars
One for StackArray
And one for QueueArray.
Only based on simple arrays (without usuing stack. Code)
I have to give 7 cars with random colors beetween red and blue.
Red for stackarray.
And blue for queue array.

So I'm extra newbie to this...

The car class is easy so I've done it... now for stack and queque class...
I created the stack class and now i need to create an array using my car constructor method and name it as a Stack array...
Then i need to use next to give my first value to the stackarray in stack method of the stack class...

I think I explained it terribly but please help T-T
[this is the chart of my classes and methods i need to add for each. (Stack and queue method are constructor to give first value to it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEZeo.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? Your class can contain an array as a member. `Car [] stack = new Car[7];` for example.

Comment: I want to create an array which stocks cars (cars have model and random color)  i have constructor method in my car class

Comment: Did you learn something by being given that implementation? Are you able to implement the queue on your own now?

Comment: He didn't teach us any of this yet he's asking for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class can have an array member. For example:

```
class CarStack {
    Car[] cars = new Car[7];
    int top = 0;

    void Push(Car c) {
        if (top != cars.Length) {
            cars[top++] = c;
        }
    }
    Car Pop() {
         if (top != 0) return cars[--top];
         else return null;
    }
}
```

And elsewhere in the program:

```
void CreateCarAndAddToStack(CarStack stack, String model, Color color)
{
    Car c = new Car(model, color);
    stack.Push(c);
}
```