# Collect int from user and add to array till they type "OK"

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

so... i need a help for my uni project. it asks to write a program that collects numbers from user and add them to array till they type ok and when they type okay show the sum of the array.
this is what i came up with till now and it recives numbers just fine but when i type ok it showes error and says its string format.
what should i do...? where have i gone wrong..?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace array_sum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] nums = new int[10];
            int i = -1;
   
            Console.WriteLine("please eneter as many numbers as you want and when your done type: OK");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            while (true && input!= "ok")
            {
                if (int.TryParse(input, out int numsum))
                {
                    nums[i + 1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Array.Resize(ref nums, nums.Length + 1);
                    numsum = nums.Sum();
                }
                else  
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
                if (input == "ok")
                {
               int  numssums = nums.Sum ();
                    Console.WriteLine(numssums);
                }
                Console.ReadKey(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? What does the compiler tell you?

Comment: System.FormatException: input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my language we have a saying "hij heeft de klok horen luiden, maar weet niet waar de klepel hangt". You grasp the concepts, but make a lot of mistakes.

I hope you can learn from example

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var nums = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("please enter as many numbers as you want and when your done type: OK");
        string input;
        while ((input = Console.ReadLine()).ToLower() != "ok")
        {
            if (int.TryParse(input, out int num))
            {
                nums.Add(num);
            }
            else  
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter a number!");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(nums.Sum());
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback it makes lots of sense.  but how can i use var for array? i must use arrays instead of lists....

Comment: @Rehy ???? WHY in heavens name. It makes ABSOLUTELY no sense to use an array here...

Comment: oh... well we're still on basics i think thats why he asked us to write this with arrays because we just got to arrays concept....

Comment: @RehyOtaku what do you mean "*just* got to the arrays concepts"? You have [another question from july](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019773/how-can-i-create-an-array-based-on-constructor-method-in-c) that already mentions array, queue and stack. That's 4 months ago! And `List` is part of the C# basics, so it should definitely be covered.

Comment: oh you see my teacher is not the same as last semester. and we started our 2nd semester  just recently and my new teacher is covering up everything from the  base. but somehow none of the two said anything about lists till now....

Comment: @RehyOtaku What's worse than one bad teacher? Two bad teachers XD. Seriously, what they are teaching you is bad. Anyhow, if you really need arrays, You already know the methods to invoke. You should be able to do the rest yourself... Or work together with a classmate.

Comment: well it can't be helped... everything is like this in my country so....yes! i just managed to solve the problem thanks to you! just finished my project! thank you so much!

Comment: @RehyOtaku by the way, you're only learning 'the basics', but you're allowed to use Linq (`Enumerable.Sum`)? Linq is already not so basic...

Comment: i dont know actually if im allowed to do that but learned that by myself in summer so im using it! : )))